# AWS network latency is high

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, iperf

I provisioned two `i2.8xlarge` VMs on `AWS`, which should have 10G network as it said on the portal.

But when I run `iperf3` test (with "-P 64", which means run with 64 TCP connections) on the VMs, it just gave me **~5Gbps** throughput. At the same time when running iperf3, the icmp ping latency is relatively high (about **19ms**).

//by the way, iperf3 with 1 TCP connection, gave me the best throughput number, which is about 7Gbps.

Do I miss any configuration/setting to my AWS deployment so that I am not able to get the high throughput and reasonable low latency?

Thanks!

Comment: "Do I miss any configuration/setting to my AWS deployment"  Probably but as this information isn't in your question no one can answer it.  I assume you have read this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html

Comment: Which region are the instances in, and are they in different availability zones?

Comment: Thanks - I will try SR-IOV. It is surprise that SR-IOV is not enabled by default. Also I am trying the TCP latency measurement by https://github.com/Microsoft/lagscope